# Out of memory using Scanner to read large file into memory

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, heap-memory

The following block of code is throwing a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception when I pass a large file into the scanner.  What is the best way to fix this?  Is the problem in the arraylist or the scanner?

```
ArrayList rawData = new ArrayList();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

while (scan.hasNext()) {
    String next = scan.next();
        rawData.add(next);
}
```

Comment: The problem here isn't the `Scanner,` it is reading the large file into memory. Can't you process it a line at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the java heap size, e.g.

```
java -Xmx6g myprogram
```

will set the heap size to 6 gigabytes. Of course there will always be a limit....

Comment: I would prefer a method that optimizes the code rather than requiring that the heap size be changed every time the program is run.  Any suggestions for that?

Comment: @trentjones21 Yes, but I'd need to know what you want to do with the data. As suggested in another answer to your question you should probably be processing each line or whatever chunk you want to work on as read rather than buffering the whole thing in memory.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is storing on the array list. Also, try to use the bufferReader and just do the processing inside the while statement instead of trying to add it to the arraylist. Here is a simple example.

```
        File file = new File("C:\\custom_programs\\reminder_list.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // do something with line.
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The default separator for a `Scanner` is whitespace.

```
public Scanner(ReadableByteChannel source) { // Your File is converted to a ReadableByteChannel from another constructor 
    this(makeReadable(Objects.requireNonNull(source, "source")),
         WHITESPACE_PATTERN);
}
```

So if your file contains many whitespace characters, you will loop so many times at

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    String next = scan.next();
    rawData.add(next);
}
```

putting in many objects in your `ArrayList` but not garbage collecting anything (ie. not freeing memory).

Each call to `next()` returns the next token until a whitespace is found. Either change the separator, increase your memory size, or change your design.

What is your file format?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading all the rows from file into `ArrayList`, do the operation you want to on each record as soon as you read it. Loading whole file into memory would cause an OOM issue if heapsize is not large enough.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    String next = scan.next();
    //do what you want to do on next
}
```